# How to remove this sidebar from Magento website?

Tags: magento2, sidebar, help-wanted

So, my problem is as following:
I tried to make a webshop using Magento. I was fiddling around, created a category, and now the title of that category is stuck to the left side of my screen.

I have tried disabling the category, but that doesn't help.

How do I remove this sidebar? Inspect element tells me it is a "navigation menu", but I have tried every option in the SM Bestshop (the theme) and nothing makes it leave.

Does anyone know where to find this specific option and disable it, or any other good advice?
Thanks!

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps it will usefull to you

1.Log in to your Magento admin panel.
2.Navigate to the "Content" tab and select "Blocks" from the dropdown menu.
3.Search for the block that is responsible for displaying the navigation menu or sidebar. It might be named something like "Main Navigation" or "Sidebar."
4.Once you've found the block, click on it to edit its settings.
5.Look for an option like "Display on All Pages" or "Display on Category Pages" and uncheck it if it's selected.
6.Save the changes to the block.

Remember to clear your cache and refresh the frontend of your webshop after making any changes to see if the sidebar has been successfully removed.

Comment: Thanks for the guide, but it turned out to be a dual theme problem.
We had 2 installed, removed one, which turned out to be a huge hassle because it broke our categories. Gonna try and ask another question to get that fixed, it's giving me a huge headache.